# Ошибки в Jquery с чем связаны?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Вроде ничего не трогал , а после перезагрузки не появляется `pointer` при наведении на активные элементы , но на них по прежнему можно нажать.

В консоли вот что выдает. С чем это связанно ?

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery.js:4)
    at i (jquery.js:4)
    at Function.n.fx.timer (jquery.js:4)
    at qb (jquery.js:4)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.g (jquery.js:4)
    at Function.dequeue (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLHtmlElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.queue (jquery.js:3)
```

Но 1 раз тыкнув в любое место на сайте и `pointer` начинает появляться , хотя ошибки по прежнему появляются.

Как лечить ?

Comment: посмотри это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592279/typeerror-p-easingthis-easing-is-not-a-function